# VSIX extension WPF styles

Tags: visual-studio-2010, vsix

I'm building a VS2010 extension (vsix) with WPF. Is there any way to reuse WPF style templates from the visual studio itself to make my control look native to Visual Studio?

A the moment I can use expressions for brushes like this:

```
xmlns:vsfx="clr-namespace:Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell;assembly=Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.10.0"
Background="{DynamicResource {x:Static vsfx:VsBrushes.ToolWindowBackgroundKey}}"
```

That's not enough, however. Can I apply a style to the whole TabControl or Label?

Comment: good question. Did you ever find anything? It's annoying to define them one by one :\. I'd like to make my button look exactly like VS button should be, by setting Style.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the the techinqe you mentioned, I found these links (also)

User Interfaces: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb165108(v=vs.110).aspx

Internal settings query: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb164716(v=vs.110).aspx

But they don't mention other than the queryable settings, to customize your style alike.