# How to reuse Visual Studio WPF styles for controls in VSIX MEF extension?

Tags: wpf, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, mef, vsix

How to reuse Visual Studio WPF styles for controls in VSIX MEF extension?

I have found some information about general using of themes in other applications [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4842736/), but probably there is other way to do it in extension inside Visual Studio?

I am writing extension with support of VS2010 and VS2012 and it would be great if it possible to use appropriate VS theme.

Actually my question is kind of duplicate to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13146629/vsix-extension-wpf-styles), still without answer.

Answer (score 3):

I found an answer, but you have to create a VSPackage to use this kind of features, although I don't remember if MEF ever made you able to display GUI elements instead of editor extension features.

User Interfaces:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb165108(v=vs.110).aspx

Internal settings query:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb164716(v=vs.110).aspx

Second link could help you to use WPF settings on your GUI extensions.

You can also query font and color setting, but I think your question is about the GUI.

At the link you provided contains the solution, I don't thik whether there is more access for settings.

Comment: The Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.VsBrushes class mentioned in the second link is the key